# Holoviews: AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'set'

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I have tried to run the Holoviews examples from the Holoviews website.

I have:

- bokeh 0.12.4.
- holoviews 1.6.2 py27_0 conda-forge

However, following any of the tutorials I get an error such as the following and am unable to debug:

AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'set'.

Is anyone able to guide me as to how to fix this?

Cheers

Ed

Comment: Please a complete but minimal code example that produces this error.

Comment: An example is from the following website:

(http://philippjfr.com/work/work-in-progress/t-sne-tutorial/)

    `%%opts Image [xaxis=None yaxis=None height=180 width=180] (cmap='gray')
hv.NdLayout({digits.target[i]: hv.Image(digits.images[i])
             for i in range(15)}, kdims=['Digit']).cols(5)`

It looks like an excellent tool but unfortunately I have not been able to play around with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using bokeh 0.12.4, the solution at this time is:

```
conda install -c ioam param
conda install -c ioam/label/dev holoviews
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes in bokeh 0.12.4, which are incompatible with HoloViews 1.6.2. We will be releasing holoviews 1.7.0 later this month, until then you have the option to downgrading to bokeh 0.12.3 or upgrading to the latest holoviews dev release with:

`conda install -c ioam/label/dev holoviews`

or

`pip install https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/archive/v1.7dev7.zip`

Comment: Hi Phillip, thanks for your prompt reply.

I tried the conda install method, restarted my kernel and imported holoviews and received the following error:

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit_count'`

I shall try going down a version in Bokeh for now.

Comment: I think this may be down to an outdated version of param. Try installing it with:

``conda install -c ioam param``

Comment: Thanks Philip, that worked. I am unable to vote up your comment but that is the solution so I'm pasting it in the "answers" section. FYI, the holoviews t-sne example doesn't work but I suspect the TSNE module has been updated and now gets unexpected arguments. I haven't had time to delve into this. Ed